# Spring App SonarQube Issue S3749

Tags: java, spring, sonarqube

I am running into an issue with my Spring Applications and SonarQube. SQ is flagging both examples with "Annotate this member with "@Autowired", "@Resource", "@Inject", or "@Value", or remove it." on the instance variable mapLoadedByDatabaseCalls

Example 1:

```
@Service
public class Service implements InitializingBean  {

    @Autowired
    private Dao dao;

    private Map<Object, Object> mapLoadedByDatabaseCalls;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        mapLoadedByDatabaseCalls= new HashMap<>(Object.class);
        ....
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
@Service
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private Dao dao;

    private Map<Object, Object> mapLoadedByDatabaseCalls;

    @PostConstruct
    private void setMap() {
        mapLoadedByDatabaseCalls= new HashMap<>(Object.class);
        ....
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to instantiate variables after DI has completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is kludgy and that your original code is better, but this will eliminate the SonarQube complaint. Initialize your map in a @Bean, then reference that as @Autowired. Load the map with data in the @PostConstruct.

```
@Bean
public Map<Object, Object> getMapLoadedByDatabaseCalls() {
    return new HashMap<>(Object.class);
}

@Autowired
private Map<Object, Object> mapLoadedByDatabaseCalls;

@PostConstruct
private void setMap() {
    ...
    // load data into the map
    mapLoadedByDatabaseCalls.put(key, value);
    ....
}
```

Comment: This looks weird, but it works. Wondering why Spring needs to manage objects when a object class is not of Spring type or have reference to Spring (no spring annotation and classed referred)?

Comment: This solves the problem, but the scope of the variable becomes application level vs class level. Does it make sense to create a bean for every single instance variable given that variable is only needed in one class? The application will end up having so many beans that are needed only in a specific class.

Answer (score 3):

A more generic solution to this that does not involve any additional annotations, is to initialize the offending variable in the class constructor.

```
public Service() {
  mapLoadedByDatabaseCalls = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution for false positives, like the one exposed by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Spring Documentation > *Initialization callbacks* section](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-lifecycle-initializingbean)

> It is recommended that you do not use the **InitializingBean** interface
>   because it unnecessarily couples the code to Spring. Alternatively,
>   use the **@PostConstruct** annotation or specify a POJO initialization
>   method.

Essentially **InitializingBean** pre-existed in Spring before the **JSR-250** [support came on Spring 2.5 onwards](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-annotation-config) (including the `@PostConstruct` annotation)

Comment: It is true that @PostConstruct is recommend rather than implementing InitializingBean, but this will not solve the SonarQube issue. SonarQube will still complain.

Answer (score -1):

The rule `S3749` describes that Spring @Component, @Controller, @Service, and @Repository classes are singletons by default, meaning only one instance of the class is ever instantiated in the application. Typically such a class might have a few static members, such as a logger, but all non-static members should be managed by Spring. That is, they should have one of these annotations: @Resource, @Inject, @Autowired or @Value.

Having non-injected members in one of these classes could indicate an attempt to manage state. Because they are singletons, such an attempt is almost guaranteed to eventually expose data from User1's session to User2.

Given the above details, Spring should be managing its all non-static members states. It all depends on the use case and should be avoided either using @Autoworied, class constructor or @PostConstruct.

*SECURITY WARNING: OWASP A3:2017. This could leak sensitive data*