Issue with SonarQube vulnerability for java (java:S3749)
I am having many cases of sonar detecting this vulnerability in the project code (not scanned for years) and im having trouble deciding which is the best solution (if it really needs one).
Inside classes anotated as @Component , I have some variables (not defined as static) that they do change when the app is running and the constantly change over the course of the class ( they are mostly maps )
An example of the code:
@Component("example")
public class exampleImpl implements example {

@Autowired
Class2 class2;

private Map < String, FormulasDTO > map1;
private Map < String, BigDecimal > map2;
private Map < String, BigDecimal > map3;

@Autowired
public exampleImpl() {}
@Override
public randomDTO calculate() {
    //logic
 } 
}

In those 3 maps i get the : Annotate this member with "@Autowired", "@Resource", "@Inject", or "@Value", or remove it.
I was thinking of getting them into the class constructor, any ideas on where i should use any of the annotations sonar says? It is just a variable inside the class, no injections from anywhere are needed.

You have some alternatives here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45939628/spring-app-sonarqube-issue-s3749.

thanks for the answer, i see there basically the constructor solution, the bean one doesnt convince me. Probably will go with the constructor but i hope to get a little more light into the spring annotations for those variables
